# SVG wont show fill d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have an SVG that I made in inkscape, now I want to fill colors in the svg according to dataset values but somehow I can't manage to show even a simple fill. Not sure how to accomplish this.

```
var svg_0 = d3.xml("continents_clean.svg", "image/svg+xml", function(xml) {
    var importedNode = document.importNode(xml.documentElement, true);
    d3.select("#viz").node().appendChild(importedNode);



var dataset;

function checkIt(data){
for (var i in data) {
            var data_clean;
            data_clean = data[i].Total
            dataset = data_clean
            fillSvg();

        }

        }

d3.json("data.json", checkIt);


function fillSvg(){
  var svg = d3.select("#level_0")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .style("fill", "purple");
            console.log(svg)
}
});
```

data

```
[{
    "Continent":"Asia.Oceania",
    "Country_Names":"Yemen",
    "Total":20
  },
  {
    "Continent":"Misc",
    "Country_Names":"World marine bunkers",
    "Total":602.2
  },
  {
    "Continent":"Misc",
    "Country_Names":"World aviation bunkers",
    "Total":477.8
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misunderstood you, so ignore what I wrote earlier about .enter().append('path').

Call each method on your selection and make sure your paths are selected and they correspond to the right json data objects. If the callback with the console.log doesn't get fired at all that means you didn't actually select you paths (because of the wrong query string) or that your dataset array doesn't have json objects.

```
d3.select("#level_0")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(dataset)
            .each(function(d, i){
              console.log(this, d, i); // <-- make sure that your data corresponds to your dom elements
            })
            .style('fill', function(d){
              return 'purple'; //<-- here you can set the color depending on values of d
            });
```

If the callback that you passed to each gets called but color hasn't changed, go to the developer tool's Elements panel and check if `fill` is actually set to purple.

Try also changing the stroke color `.style('stroke', 'purple')` and see if it changes the stroke of the path.

Good luck!

Comment: .enter().append('path') does not work as well.. there is no error on console.

Comment: I missed one thing. Since you are appending path element you need to set "d" attribute (selection.attr('d', 'path string')). You can read about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

Comment: what is 'path string' here? I wnt like to change the values of d just its style

Comment: If you read the article that I gave you, you'll now what 'path string' is. Did you only want to change a color of the path that inkscape generated or you wanted to dynamically append path attribute and color it?

Comment: would just like to color the element, dont need to append it